# Micro-lags with fresh install of Ubuntu Cosmic

Tags: 18.10

I've recently upgraded (fresh install) of Ubuntu 18.10 to my PC using Ivy-Bridge onboard Intel HD2500 graphics, 24GB of ram and an Intel SSD. 
However I've noticed a lot of microlagging since install. Eg I'll be typing and the letters being typed are occasionally delayed by up to a second. Music that is playing also randomly pauses for a second before resuming.

CPU graph is flat (averaging 10-20%).

Output of *lshw -c video*

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Everything else is running fine quickly. Videos play fine. Mouse isn't laggy. Any ideas?

Comment: I would run something like `glances` & look for IO wait or something else going 'red' or out-of-wack.  I mentioned IO wait as if using cheap (wd green for example) hdd's, which have long warranties, they can 'pause' when they have errors to 'fix' it so as to not cause warranty claim (not reporting an error), but this shows up in IO wait.  This is just a thought I'd explore if in your position (not knowing your hardware)

Comment: if you run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` does it install any intel-related software? if so let it install and reboot and see if it's better. this could simply be linux/ubuntu's poor support of intel HD graphics.

Comment: `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libllvm8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-radeon`
Will see what happens after reboot.

Comment: Much the same after reboot. 
@guiverc Whenever the music halts, /usr/lib/snapd/snapd is at the top of the **glances** output, around 10-15% cpu. Nothing else seems amiss. No HDD's, just the Intel SSD.

Comment: I have an old 9500GT graphics card lying around. Would putting that in potentially be better than the Intel HD2500?